# Unable to count database users

Tags: php, count

I can't count my users in the database with my current configurations.

```
<?php
require_once 'scripts/app_config.php';
mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST,DATABASE_USER,DATABASE_PASS,DATABASE_NAME);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "There are: ". $num . " users in the database";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Your query only returns 1 row, so I presume the problem you're having is that it always outputs: *There are 1 users in the database*.

You should instead use:

```
$num = mysqli_fetch_array($query)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use `COUNT(*)` OR use `mysql_num_rows`

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$num = $row[0];

echo "There are: ". $num . " users in the database";
```

**Note :** `mysql_*` function is deprecated, move on `mysqli_*` function asap.

Comment: I wouldn't advise using `mysql_num_rows`; all that means is that a ton of rows will be returned unnecessarily.